# jQuery include more than 1 time?

Tags: jquery

jQuery should be loaded only 1 time but the website features work only when I add it 2 times.

This works:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/forum_fn.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="/jquery_base/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/jquery_base/jquery.notify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

When I remove the second jquery include. The features does not work. Why do I have to load it twice? I have no possibilty to add code in a php file. I have to use html templates.

thank you for help.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: Please explain 'works' and 'does not work'

Comment: The guess is, that you overwrite jQuery references within `forum_fn.js`. Check the jQuery object after the inclusion of `forum_fn.js`.

Comment: check your `forum_fn.js` may be it creates error or something

Comment: When you try to load the same script second time, it actually doesn't download it again because it is cached. So this is not the case.

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed I cant see an error. Sirko: yes propably how do I find it and what can I do? Sorry I am not good in it. I know its a dumb question. The forum_fn.js code is to much to copy and paste 733 lines.

Comment: @Koninos: yes, I want to load it only 1 time but when I load it only on top the code after forum_fn.js does not work anymore. So sirko is true. Anything overwrites it.